# How to save changes to an Edit view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC Application which displays items from a database. Each item has a Details and an Edit view. The Edit view allows you user to make changes to the record by displaying the values. The problem I am having is that I cannot get the changes that are made to save.

- I believe that the first edit action result is used to display the records when the user clicks on "Edit" in the "Index" view. The second edit action result should be callled when the user presses the "Save Changes" button in the Edit view.
- When debugging I did find that the values such as "item.Item_No_" where not being populated by the values in the View

I have provided code from my Controller,

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Nick

```
        public ActionResult Edit(string itemNo)
    {
        LinnWorksItemViewModel model = new LinnWorksItemViewModel(_data.Connection.ConnectionString, itemNo);
        return View(model);

        // Declare item no here?
            foreach (string upload in Request.Files)
            {
                if (!Request.Files[upload].HasFile()) continue;
                string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "uploads/";
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[upload].FileName);
                Request.Files[upload].SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, fileName));
            }
           return View(model);       
    }

       [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Item item, string itemNo)
    {
        LinnWorksItemViewModel model = new LinnWorksItemViewModel(_data.Connection.ConnectionString, itemNo);

        try
        {
            Item _linnItem = _data.Items
                .Where(x => x.Item_No_ == item.Item_No_)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            _linnItem.Description = item.Description;
            _linnItem.Search_Description = item.Extended_Description;
            _linnItem.Default_Barcode = item.Default_Barcode;
            _linnItem.Variations_Group_Code = item.Variations_Group_Code;
            _linnItem.LinnWork_Category_Code = item.LinnWork_Category_Code;
            _linnItem.Unit_Cost = item.Unit_Cost;
            _linnItem.Unit_Price = item.Unit_Price;
            _linnItem.Shipping_Agent_Code = item.Shipping_Agent_Code;
            _linnItem.Package_Group_Code = item.Package_Group_Code;
            _linnItem.Stockkeeping_Units = item.Stockkeeping_Units;
            _linnItem.Weight = item.Weight;
            _linnItem.Width = item.Width;
            _linnItem.Height = item.Height;
            _linnItem.Depth = item.Depth;

            _data.SubmitChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = ex.Message;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, _data is just defined as this: private TitaniumDataContext _data = new TitaniumDataContext();

Comment: What is the values of item and itemNo in your post action?

Comment: In your edit view, are you using `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Item_No_)`?

Comment: I do have other, simpler MVC Edits that do save correctly, but finding this one more complex. This one has many other fields stored in the accordion which are values in different tables, would I need to declare them all like I have for the Item fields in order to get the Edit to work?

Comment: Sorry yes, it is Linq to Sql. As you can tell I am a beginner!

Comment: I have other values in the View that are stored in different <div>'s in an accordion. Will all of these values have to be in the controller in order for the Edit to work? @NikoDrašković

Comment: Could you try to surround your entire Edit action code with `if(ModelState.IsValid){ //code here } return View();`. If you're using your view properly, you should have a `@using(Html.BeginForm()){..}` and several validators. If there is anything wrong with the data you're submitting, they should scream the errors back to you. This is MVC 4?

Comment: @NikoDrašković Yes this is MVC 4. I have implemented the If(ModelState.IsValid), ran the application and no error messages have come up

Comment: And `item.Item_No_` is not populated by the view? Do you have the `HiddenFor` as mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: If I understand you correctly then yes I think so, for each of my records I have it like this: <th style="width:20%">Item No.</th>
                    <td style="width:30%">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item.Item_No_)</td>. No, item.Item_No_ is not being populated when I debug

Comment: Could you paste your edit view into pastebin.com and put the link in your question?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, here you go @NikoDrašković http://pastebin.com/bnzfpUP7